# Angular default route redirectTo with loadChildren

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following app:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'demo', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'demo',  loadChildren: () => ChildModule },
];

imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
],
```

And it is using this module in `loadChildren`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',  component: DemoComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'some', component: SomeComponent },
      { path: 'other', component: OtherComponent },
    ],
  },
];

imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
],
```

If I start the app there are two routes defined:

`http://localhost:4200/demo/some`

`http://localhost:4200/demo/other`

Also working is:

`http://localhost:4200/some`

`http://localhost:4200/other`

When I navigate to `http://localhost:4200/` it's not redirecting to `http://localhost:4200/demo`!

So why are the routes `/some` and `/other` working and the redirect isn't?

Comment: You can try by making the following change in your path `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/demo', pathMatch: 'full' }`

Comment: thanks but it's also not working

Answer (score -1):

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'demo', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'someother',  loadChildren: () => ChildModule },
];

imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
],

=======================================================

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "", redirectTo: "some", pathMatch: "full"
    },
    {
    path: "some",
    component: SomeComponent
    },
    {
    path: "other",
    component: OtherComponent
    }    

];

imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
],
```

Comment: But the child module has its own router-outlet in DemoComponent and you removed DemoComponent?